# Primeng p-table virtual scroll display previous rows when using row grouping

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable, virtualscroll

I'm trying to create a `p-table` that has grouped rows but I'm not able to correctly apply the virtual scroll feature.

`p-table` is part of the [PrimeNg](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table) framework.

The issue is when scrolling and doing a lazy loading (which, actually is just appending some rows), the table display previous rows instead of the new ones. But if I load all my data and scroll from the beginning to the end, all rows are correctly displayed. I assume this is a problem during the refreshing of the table after a lazy load.

For a better comprehension of this issue I've reproduced it on a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-8mtvwc

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I am not sure if I can see issue in stackblitz you attached. Are you sure it is correct one?

Comment: I've recorded the issue reproduced on stackblitz: https://gofile.io/?c=GYNJhF

Comment: Did you tried adding a tail to the name, it might be faker using the same name
Try const acpName = faker.company.companyName(0) + faker.random.number({min:1, max:10}); or something like that

Answer (score 2):

1) With the grouping, the `totalRecords` you set is not correct. We have to take the count of the title-rows and add it to the `totalRecords` as well:

```
this.totalRecords = this.filteredInvoices.length + Object.keys(this.rowGroupMetadata).length;
```

2) Slicing always from the beginning does not quite make sense for me. We should only push new rows to the table. So instead of:

```
  loadChunk(init?: boolean) {
   ...
      data = [...this.filteredInvoices]
    } else {
      data = this.filteredInvoices.slice(0, endIndex); // <===
    }
    ..
  }
```

you can do something like that:

```
  loadChunk(init?: boolean) {
    ...
    const startAt = this.displayedInvoices ? this.displayedInvoices.length : 0;
    let endAt = startAt + this.MAX_ROWS;

    if (endAt >= this.filteredInvoices.length) {
      endAt = this.filteredInvoices.length;
    }

    const newInvoices = this.filteredInvoices.slice(startAt, endAt);

    this.displayedInvoices.push(...newInvoices);
  }
```

Updated your blizz, hope that helps: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-psbm78?file=src/app/home-encoding/home-encoding.component.ts

Cheers Chris

Comment: Thanks. It in facts resolve the issue but their is stil something weird happening. If I scroll to load a chunk and then make a search, the table does not resize to fit the actual number of rows. You can see it on this video: https://gofile.io/?c=RhkPIm

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that PrimeNg internally uses the row height for virtual scrolling, which always causes issues when rows have different heights for example. Since your rows are grouped your likely have a group header row, which also kicks the calculation in the ass.